# How do I split my USB sound card recognized as 5.1 into 3 stereo channels?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a NI Komplete Audio 6, and I want to use its stereo channels separately, not all the outputs combined as 5.1.

It is recognized by Ubuntu, however I only get the choice of using it in 2.1, 4.1, 5.0 or 5.1. To get proper audio on the first stereo channel, I've had to select 2.1 and then disable lfe-mixing in `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` so that the low frequencies do no get sent to the non-existing sub-woofer.

I would like at least to be able to use my sound card in 2.0, and at best to have it come up as 3 virtual 2.0 devices in Ubuntu. I have already tried to fiddle with pulseaudio profiles but with no success.

Here is my `aplay -L` output: http://pastebin.com/rch6dLzJ

Any ideas?

EDIT: Using the `asound.conf` provided in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106186/how-to-split-7-1-soundcard-outputs-to-4-stereo-outs-with-alsa) and adapting it to six channels did not work. Also, I am also asking about having my device be properly recognized as 2.0 capable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching and fiddling around some more, I finally found an interesting [Archlinux wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Splitting_7.1_into_5.1.2B2.0), which allowed me to come up with this piece of code to be added at the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=KompleteAudio6_12 sink_properties=device.description="Komplete\ Audio\ 6\ Output\ 1/2\ (Main)" remix=no master=alsa_output.usb-Native_Instruments_Komplete_Audio_6_582A9505-00.analog-surround-51 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-left,front-right
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=KompleteAudio6_34 sink_properties=device.description="Komplete\ Audio\ 6\ Output\ 3/4" remix=no master=alsa_output.usb-Native_Instruments_Komplete_Audio_6_582A9505-00.analog-surround-51 channels=2 master_channel_map=front-center,lfe channel_map=front-left,front-right
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=KompleteAudio6_56 sink_properties=device.description="Komplete\ Audio\ 6\ Output\ 5/6\ (S/PDIF)" remix=no master=alsa_output.usb-Native_Instruments_Komplete_Audio_6_582A9505-00.analog-surround-51 channels=2 master_channel_map=rear-left,rear-right channel_map=front-left,front-right

set-default-sink KompleteAudio6_12
```

I now have 3 devices with Stereo output linked to the correct ports on my sound card. I guess this is easily adaptable for any other sound card.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing your solution. I had the same issue with a X32/M32 and X-USB multichannel USB sound card. Do you happen to know how to make a similar configuration for the inputs? (just changing the words 'output' to 'input' in the code resulted in pulseaudio not starting unfortunately and I was not able to find anything about remapping inputs)

Comment: @Rick change the word `sink` to `source` and you're done, assuming you want to map the same channels.

Comment: Note you will probably have to run `pactl list sinks` and get your own device name, the numbers after `Komplete_Audio_6_` are probably different and mine was also postfixed with `.analog-stero-out-ab` instead. I applied the above fix to correct DOOM 2016 in Proton assuming I had a 5.1 system - because it sees (L,R,Aux*4 I assume). Without the fix I could not hear any sounds behind me in game. You can also use `pulsemixer` or `alsamixer` to see the channels listed which can help diagnose the issue.